# Magento 2.2.5 Error on WHM EasyApache4

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I installed my Magento 2 to an Apache environment. I know I may have some misconfiguration errors. Any Ideas how to fix this one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed my own problem. I will share it in here because someone might experience this one working with Magento 2 with WHM.

I imported the WHM EasyApache Profile to my other WHM Server that has a problem.

This is the content of the WHM Profile for Magento 2 that is in the form of JSON file. The filename is m2.json

> {
>      "name" : "Apache Working Profile for M2",
>      "tags" : [
>         "Apache Working Profile for M2"
>      ],
>      "version" : "0.1",
>      "desc" : "Apache Working Profile for M2",
>      "pkgs" : [
>         "ea-apache24",
>         "ea-apache24-config",
>         "ea-apache24-config-runtime",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_authn_anon",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_authn_socache",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_authz_dbm",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_bwlimited",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_cgi",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_deflate",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_expires",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_headers",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_mpm_prefork",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_proxy",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_proxy_http",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_proxy_wstunnel",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_security2",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_ssl",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_suexec",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_suphp",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_unique_id",
>         "ea-apache24-mod_version",
>         "ea-apache24-tools",
>         "ea-apr",
>         "ea-apr-util",
>         "ea-brotli",
>         "ea-cpanel-tools",
>         "ea-documentroot",
>         "ea-libcurl",
>         "ea-libmcrypt",
>         "ea-libnghttp2",
>         "ea-libtidy",
>         "ea-libxml2",
>         "ea-modsec-sdbm-util",
>         "ea-nghttp2",
>         "ea-openssl",
>         "ea-php-cli",
>         "ea-php-cli-lsphp",
>         "ea-php54-libc-client",
>         "ea-php70",
>         "ea-php70-pear",
>         "ea-php70-php-bcmath",
>         "ea-php70-php-cli",
>         "ea-php70-php-common",
>         "ea-php70-php-curl",
>         "ea-php70-php-devel",
>         "ea-php70-php-ftp",
>         "ea-php70-php-gd",
>         "ea-php70-php-iconv",
>         "ea-php70-php-intl",
>         "ea-php70-php-ioncube10",
>         "ea-php70-php-litespeed",
>         "ea-php70-php-mbstring",
>         "ea-php70-php-mcrypt",
>         "ea-php70-php-mysqlnd",
>         "ea-php70-php-pdo",
>         "ea-php70-php-posix",
>         "ea-php70-php-soap",
>         "ea-php70-php-xml",
>         "ea-php70-php-zip",
>         "ea-php70-runtime",
>         "ea-profiles-cpanel"
>      ]
>   }

And I have uploaded my m2.json profile to WHM EasyApache profile importer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use cPanel WHM and Magento 2.3.0 ( at the time of this post 21JAN2019

I finally have Magento 2.3 working as fast as possible on my server. I searched all over for the perfect EasyApache4 config but didn't find it. So here is my working JSON file:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96510589478813449603

use that as a profile and your Magento will fly.

Here is the json file in notepad:

Apache 2.4

config

config-runtime

mod_allowmethods

mod_asis

mod_auth_digest

mod_authnz_ldap

mod_authz_dbd

mod_buffer

mod_bwlimited

mod_cache

mod_cache_disk

mod_cache_socache

mod_cgid

mod_charset_lite

mod_cpanel

mod_dav

mod_dav_fs

mod_dav_lock

mod_dbd

mod_deflate

mod_env

mod_expires

mod_ext_filter

mod_fcgid

mod_file_cache

mod_headers

mod_http2

mod_imagemap

mod_ldap

mod_mime_magic

mod_mpm_worker

mod_proxy

mod_proxy_fcgi

mod_proxy_http

mod_proxy_scgi

mod_proxy_wstunnel

mod_security2

mod_socache_memcache

mod_speling

mod_ssl

mod_substitute

mod_suexec

mod_suphp

mod_unique_id

mod_usertrack

mod_version

mod_vhost_alias

mod_watchdog

tools
PHP 5.6

build

libc-client

pear

php-bcmath

php-bz2

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-dba

php-debuginfo

php-devel

php-enchant

php-exif

php-fileinfo

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-gettext

php-gmp

php-iconv

php-imap

php-intl

php-ioncube

php-ldap

php-litespeed

php-mbstring

php-mcrypt

php-mysqlnd

php-odbc

php-pdo

php-pgsql

php-posix

php-process

php-pspell

php-snmp

php-soap

php-sockets

php-sourceguardian

php-suhosin

php-tidy

php-xml

php-xmlrpc

php-zendguard

php-zip

runtime
PHP 7.2

build

libc-client

libc-client-devel

libc-client-static

pear

php-bcmath

php-bz2

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-dba

php-dbg

php-devel

php-enchant

php-exif

php-fileinfo

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-gettext

php-gmp

php-iconv

php-imap

php-intl

php-ioncube10

php-ldap

php-litespeed

php-mbstring

php-mysqlnd

php-odbc

php-opcache

php-pdo

php-pgsql

php-phalcon

php-posix

php-process

php-pspell

php-snmp

php-soap

php-sockets

php-sourceguardian

php-tidy

php-xml

php-xmlrpc

php-zip

runtime

scldevel
Additional Packages

apr

apr-util

apr-util-ldap

brotli

cpanel-tools

documentroot

libcurl

libmcrypt

libnghttp2

libtidy

libxml2

modsec-sdbm-util

nghttp2

openssl

openssl-devel

php-cli

php-cli-lsphp

profiles-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

I setup Magento last week and had to mess around to get everything required to run it.

Here is my EasyApache 4 module config

Apache 2.4
config

config-runtime

mod_bwlimited

mod_cache

mod_cache_disk

mod_cgid

mod_env

mod_headers

mod_mpm_worker

mod_proxy

mod_proxy_http

mod_proxy_wstunnel

mod_ssl

mod_suphp

mod_version

tools

PHP 5.5
libc-client

pear

php-bcmath

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-devel

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-imap

php-litespeed

php-mcrypt

php-mysqlnd

php-pdo

php-posix

php-sockets

php-xml

runtime

PHP 5.6
libc-client

pear

php-bcmath

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-devel

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-imap

php-litespeed

php-mcrypt

php-mysqlnd

php-pdo

php-posix

php-sockets

php-xml

runtime

PHP 7.0
libc-client

pear

php-bcmath

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-devel

php-fileinfo

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-iconv

php-imap

php-intl

php-ioncube10

php-litespeed

php-mbstring

php-mcrypt

php-mysqlnd

php-pdo

php-posix

php-soap

php-sockets

php-xml

php-zip

runtime

PHP 7.1
libc-client

pear

php-bcmath

php-calendar

php-cli

php-common

php-curl

php-devel

php-fileinfo

php-fpm

php-ftp

php-gd

php-imap

php-litespeed

php-mcrypt

php-mysqlnd

php-pdo

php-posix

php-sockets

php-xml

runtime

Others
apr

apr-util

brotli

cpanel-tools

documentroot

libcurl

libmcrypt

libnghttp2

libxml2

nghttp2

openssl

php-cli

php-cli-lsphp

profiles-cpanel

Comment: I also did alot of clearing my APACHE error log, refreshing the page and seeing what errors i had

Comment: I just tried but it got worst. if  I load the page it will download the index file

Comment: Have you run setup?
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

Comment: Yes I did. And now it's not working.

Comment: Might be worth starting again

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth starting again;
Uninstall Magento;
php bin/magento setup:uninstall

Reinstall with composer;

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition

Run the setup

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web.html

CHMOD all of the files and directories to your server requirements.  My install is at public_html/magdev running SuPHP, so from Public_HTML in SSH

find magdev -type d -exec chmod 755 -R '{}' \;

find magdev -type f -exec chmod 644 -R '{}' \;

Go to the htaccess file in root of the install and set as developer (remove the #)

Then run;

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cron:run

If you want the sample data, you can run this

php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

With the server settings provided and that install method everything worked fine.

Comment: It's from my local server. I migrated it to the apache whm and its not working.

Comment: So check your server by doing a CLEAN install as above, you can always remove it.  It wont take long if you use the composer method

Comment: If clean install is ok, use this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server

Comment: Oh and one other thing, the pub/static folder is where all of the cache files are stored.  Cache files from your local host will just cause problems on the Apache server

Best to delete the cache as per the link above then redeploy it all

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Just fixed it right now in my own. I have a working m2 installed in another WHM. and I exported the Easyapache profile from that whm and imported to my current Magento 2 that has an error.  So therefore the error was just the WHM itself I did not properly configured the modules of apache.

Comment: Cool, glad that you got it sorted out!.  Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Thank you also Anthony for your effort. I really appreciate it!